# Python to count number of occurrence of each line, in huge text file

Tags: python, count

A big text file has millions of lines, that I want to count the number of occurrence of each line (how many times the line appear in the file).

[image]

Current solution I am using, is as below. It works but very slow.

What is the better way to do so?

```
from collections import Counter

crimefile = open("C:\\temp\\large text_file.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
yourResult = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in crimefile.readlines()]

yourResult = sum(yourResult, [])

result = dict((i, yourResult.count(i)) for i in yourResult)
output = sorted((value,key) for (key,value) in result.items())

print (Counter(yourResult))
```

Comment: What are you expecting *sum()* to do with these data? Surely that raises TypeError

Answer (score 4):

We can use a single for loop to do this. We don't have to strip the new line character because every line will have it.

**Solution**

```py
counter = {}
with open('filename/path', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line not in counter:
            counter[line] = 1
        else:
            counter[line] += 1
print(counter)
```

**Time Complexity**

```
O(n)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Hope you don't mind I chose another, which the output looks neater, as the answer. :)

Comment: @MarkK It's okay. I decided to be verbose because I wanted anyone reading this code to understand it. The if/else statement can be replaced with this ```counter[line] = 1 + counter.get(line, 0)```

Answer (score 4):

Using a `defaultdict` and looping over lines, instead of reading everything to memory.

```
counter = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
with open("C:\\temp\\large text_file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in map(str.strip, file):
        counter[line] += 1
counter = dict(counter)
print(counter)
```

Tested with `timeit` and 10k lines of text, roughly 40x faster on my machine.

E: Changed the string strip to use mapping instead based on Fred's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You do not qualify what you mean by "very slow".

I have a text file comprised of 2.5 million different lines which can be processed in ~1.3s as follows:

```
from timeit import timeit

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt'

def get_counts():
    d = {}
    line_count = 0

    with open(FILENAME) as f:
        for line in map(str.strip, f):
            d[line] = d.get(line, 0) + 1
            line_count += 1
    key_count = len(d)
    print(f'{line_count=}, {key_count=}')
    return d

print(timeit(get_counts, number=1))
```

**Output:**

```
line_count=2500000, key_count=2500000
1.2901516660003836
```

**Notes:**

You could use Counter or defaultdict from the *collections* module but they are both slower than the strategy shown in this answer.

As I understand the required functionality you probably don't need to strip the lines. If you omit that you could see a further improvement of ~12%

Comment: I did some benchmarking against the `defaultdict` method both show very similar speeds. Using the mapping for stripping like you gave a nice speed boost of 8%. I tested both with 100k randomized integers as the lines in the file / 100 timeit iters, so maybe that's the reason for different results...

Comment: @Tzane Hardware and Python version are likely to be significant factors when benchmarking especially as 3.11 contains numerous performance enhancements. I'm running 3.11.1 on a 10 core 3GHz Xeon